# Export menu and tooltips for Toast UI Chart not working

Tags: toast-ui-chart

Is Toast UI Chart compatible with Angular? I followed the instructions to set it up and copy & pasted one of their examples, but the tooltips and export menu aren't working. Here is what I get:

[image: Toast UI Chart screenshot]

The export menu is for some reason at the bottom, overflowing the container, and an unstyled list that doesn't actually do anything. When hovering over the graph, nothing happens (there should be tooltips popping up). Toggling lines via the legend works, so it's not like the entire thing is broken. I am using Angular 9 and version 3.11.2 of tui-chart.

I'm also curious how to hide/remove the entire legend. I couldn't find anything about that in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Check your project's main css file.
Need to import "~tui-chart/dist/tui-chart.css" there.

Answer (score 0):

Add to cdn css link on header

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://uicdn.toast.com/chart/latest/toastui-chart.min.css" />
```

then check all ui related issue resolve